Can't access variable inside class from async promise
For some reason I can't access variable test from function getTest.
export class Test {
    test: string;

    constructor() {
        this.test = "123";
    }

    async getTest() {
        return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
            try {
                console.log(this.test);
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
    }
}

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'test')  

How should I access value from promise?

Use an arrow function: (resolve, reject) =>

Not related to the issue but still: Is it an anti-pattern to use async/await inside of a new Promise() constructor?

Also note that the callback to the Promise constructor does not need to be and should not be async.

Unmitigated, thank you very much!

@QreatyMeaty Happy to help. I would also advise not creating a new Promise when you're already using an async method though.
